# MediatR usage in DDD with handler not found error

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr

i'm learning about CQRS and implementing MediatR in a DDD project.
I've the following project structure:

```
Domain
    - Commands
        - Requests
        - Handlers
    - Models
    - Interfaces
        - Repositories

CrossCutting
    NativeInjectionBootstrapper.cs

Presentation
    - Controllers
```

So, in Presentation Project i've inject all repositories and other dependencies with the `NativeInjectionBootstrapper.cs` and i added `services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup))` in Startup.cs.

In `Domain > Commands > Request` i implement the `IRequest<>` interface.

In `Domain > Commands > Handlers` i implement the `IRequestHandler<>` interface.

The interfaces are injected successfully, but when request to controller i receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2 [Domain.Commands.Requests.Product.NewProductRequest,System.String]. 
Register your handlers with the container. 
See the samples in GitHub for examples.
```

I've looking for help here and someone suggest another type of add MediatR in startup like `services.AddMediatR(typeof(AddEducationCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);` but i've no success.

I was search about how to register the handlers but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: When I use just one project, everything works ok, but when I separate into projects, i get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add the Domain Project Assembly in the `services.AddMediatR()` and it's work.

Like this:

```
services.AddMediatR(
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Buzzy.Presentation"), 
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Buzzy.Domain")
);
```

I don't know if this is a correct way, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register MediatR with the assemblies where your handlers are defined:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(AddEducationCommandHandler).Assembly);
```

Have you read the docs: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection